# Not Able to Align div to the right in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I am making a  simple website with Bootstrap but problem here is that I want to assign my 2nd div (the one with lorem text) to the right of the webpage. But it's going down even when I tried using ms-0 and CSS text-align ? Can You please suggest me that how can I assign that div in the right of the page?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="serviceoffers">
  <div class="conatiner heading text-center">
    <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold font-size">What We Offer</h1>
    <p class="text-center lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

    <div class="container">

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-10 offset-lg-0 font-graph">
        <div class=" nameLan my-3 ">
          <h2>Java</h2>

          <div class="progress-bar progress progress-bar-striped bg-success progress-bar-animated rounded" style="width: 100%;">100%</div>
        </div>

        <div class="nameLan my-3">
          <h2>HTML & CSS</h2>

          <div class="progress-bar progress w-75 progress-bar-striped bg-info progress-bar-animated rounded" style="width: 100%;">75%</div>
        </div>

        <div class="nameLan my-3">
          <h2>ReactJs</h2>

          <div class="progress-bar  progress w-55 progress-bar-striped bg-info progress-bar-animated rounded" style="width: 100%;">55%</div>
        </div>

        <div class="nameLan my-3">
          <h2>C++</h2>
          <div class="progress-bar  progress w-55 progress-bar-striped bg-danger progress-bar-animated rounded" style="width: 100%; height: 15px;">55%</div>
        </div>

        <div class="nameLan my-3">
          <h2>Python</h1>

            <div class="progress-bar  progress w-50 progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated rounded" style="width: 100%;">50%</div>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12 servicediv ml-auto ">
        <!-- How to align this to right ? -->
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 service-icons">
            <i class="fa-2x fas fa-laptop align-self-start" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-10 col-10">
            <h2>Hi there</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus ullam quas non rem nostrum, laborum enim harum hic esse sed totam asperiores impedit alias! Maiores distinctio natus, illo at accusantium veniam enim atque? Ipsum voluptate
              sint commodi totam maiores cumque!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code? It seems to be working for me https://jsfiddle.net/onbqevm1/

Comment: What's with the empty container element? Normally containers shouldn't be nested.

Comment: View the demo I created from your snippet in full screen mode. Your column _does_ go to the right, but only for the breakpoints you've specified. You haven't addressed smaller screens. Answers depend on you telling us how you want your columns to behave from mobile on up. Please revise to be more clear. Review the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) so you understand all the relevant concepts.

Comment: On more careful reading I suspect that you want the icons column first in vertical order and second in horizontal order. Again, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way. you can put the `<p>` and `<h1>` inside a `div` with display `flex`

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold font-size">What We Offer</h1>
  <p class="text-center lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 
   adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

you can adjust the position just like you want
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Comment: Restructuring away from a columnar layout isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end">
  <h1>What We Offer</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Restructuring away from a columnar layout isn't necessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.